# Time disappears on close ck on stove

Tags: stove

Changed time during day light saving time now it doesn’t appear.

Have to push clock button to tell time. Need to keep time showing.

Comment: What model of stove are we talking about? We would need that to figure it out.

Comment: How in the world do you expect us to answer that?  Please give us enough info to know what stove you have.  **Have you tried searching the internet for the instructions to your stove**.